# Kafka Memory leak

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, bigdata, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

Running the latest Kafka helm charts, https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts, we are experiencing huge exponentially growing memory leaks that are causing our GCP clusters to crash after two days of running. I have raised the issue https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/issues/296, but with no avail.

I still have not been able to trace the source of leak however I think it may be from the prometheus exporter.

Are there any known fixes for this issue?

### Updates,

disabled jmx in the chart values, yet we are still experiencing massive leakage, the majority coming from the control-center pod

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a consumer that is stuck in a crash loop can build up ridiculous amounts of memory. We spent a long time tracking one down that filled terabytes of information rather quickly, turns out it submitted the crash log as a record. Double check the consumers and producers just in case it is something similar

Comment: we are only running a source connector and two influxdb sinks, they all seem to be running fine. We still cant narrow down what is filling all of the memory

Comment: the leak also appears in the control center instance which makes me think it might be something to do with the metrics

Comment: I'll have to think about it some more lol, I'll leave this answer in case someone else comes across it. What versions of Prometheus and Kafka are you using?

Comment: @SamPalmer Never mind, Kafka latest, have you looked into the jmx metrics as far as the jvm, topic, bandwidth info yet?

Comment: using kafka cp-enterprise:5.2.1 with solsson/kafka-prometheus-jmx-exporter, which are the default settings in the official helm charts

Comment: any ideas in how to identify if any java streams are being left open?

Comment: @SamPalmer If you are just looking for some answers, you might be able to temporarily setup the jmx Port for external access and use jconsole to connect over IP, just for less moving parts, but I'm not sure where I'd start without seeing the stats

Comment: @SamPalmer you can try to telnet to the jmx port from a different pod to see if there is a connection maybe?